# Callable Dao dynamic method

Tags: java, multithreading, class, jpa, callable

I need to do something like this:

Creating a callable, and pass it to a ThreadPoolExecutor. The Callable in fact is a Dao, which should execute different functions. Because its not possible to pass parameters to the call() function directly, i thought about doing something like this, to immediately execute the code when an object is created:

Creating a class like this:

```
public class FooRecordDatabaseInsert {
    static {
        //execute some code
    }
}
```

The callable could now look something like this:

```
@Override
    public Foo call() {
        this.startOperation();
    }
```

But i have to pass parameters, like an Entity to this class.
Is there a good possibility to create a class which has one function with parameters, which is immediately executed, when the object is created?

Or may there be an completely different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a Callable that calls a method of a DAO with parameters.

So you want something like this:

```
final MyDAO dao = ...;
Callable<Foo> callable = new Callable<>() {
    @Override
    public Foo call() {
        return dao.someMethod(1, 2, 3);
    }
};
```

This is called an anonymous inner class, and you should definitely know about them before doing advanced, complex, multi-threading stuff.

With Java 8, you can use lambdas to make things even simpler:

```
MyDAO dao = ...;
Callable<Foo> callable = () -> dao.someMethod(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, never considered a solution like this. I will read about the anonymous inner class, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer using a constructor having the Entity as argument.

Comment: But what about returning exceptions ? Is this possible via a constructor ?

Comment: Your class should have an entity private field. The constructor will only set the value of that field with the entity argument. The processing that may cause exception will be in the call method. Of course, you can throw exceptions there.